# plotting an equation with double summations

Tags: plotting, summation

Thank you so much for the helpful comments. Now able to manage to plot all the functions.

```
Remove[q, qC, IIC]

ass = {d > 1, num > 0, \[CapitalDelta] > 0, t > 0, n >= 0};

q[\[Nu]_, num_, \[CapitalDelta]_, t_] := 
 1/num (1 + 
    2 Exp[-\[Nu]] NSum[
      Sin[(\[Pi] d)/num]/((\[Pi] d)/num) Exp[-d \[CapitalDelta]^2] 
       Cos[(\[Pi] d)/num (2 t + 1)] \[Nu]^(n + d/2)/Sqrt[
       n! (n + d)!], {d, 1, 10}, {n, 0, 10}])

AbsoluteTiming[Table[q[2, 4, 0.2, t], {t, 0, 200, 20}]]

Plot[q[2.0, 4.0, 0.2, t], {t, 0, 200}]

qC[\[Nu]_, num_, \[CapitalDelta]_, t_] := 
  1/num (1 + 
     2 Exp[-\[Nu]] Sum[
       Sin[(\[Pi] d)/num]/((\[Pi] d)/num) Exp[-d \[CapitalDelta]^2] 
        Cos[(\[Pi] d)/num (2 t + 1)] \[Nu]^(n + d/2)/Sqrt[
        n! (n + d)!], {d, 1, 20}, {n, 0, 20}]);

AbsoluteTiming[Table[qC[2., 4., 0.2, t], {t, 0, 200, 10}]]

ListPlot[Table[{t, qC[2, 4, 0.2, t]}, {t, 0, 200}]]

IIC[\[Nu]_, num_, \[CapitalDelta]_] :=
```

Log[2, num] - 
   Sum[(q[[Nu], num, [CapitalDelta], t]) Log[2, 
      q[[Nu], num, [CapitalDelta], t]], {t, 0, num - 1}];
AbsoluteTiming[Table[IIC[[Nu], 4, 0.2], {[Nu], 1, 200, 20}]]
ListPlot[Table[{[Nu], IIC[[Nu], 4, 0.2]}, {[Nu], 1, 50}], 
 PlotRange -> All, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]

Comment: `I` and `N` are built-in symbols, so don't use as custom function or variable names.  Please try to come up with a *minimal* (as short as possible) test case that demonstrates the problem you are having, and describe the problem and the question in detail. If you simply post a large body of code, saying that it doesn't work, but not explaining what you're trying to do and what went wrong, then it's unlikely people will help.

Comment: Thank you Verbeia for the editing!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first plot just works fine, although it takes a long time.

```
Plot[q[2.0, 4.0, 0.2, t], {t, 0, 200}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The table contains the same values, because you sample the periodic function periodically.

The data of the second plot is sampled badly. You should increase the frequency:

```
ListPlot[Table[{t, qC[2, 4, 0.2, t]}, {t, 0, 20, .1}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The last plot doesn't work because your function IIC has `t` both in its argument list as well as in the iterator of the `Sum`.

Comment: thank you so much Sjoered C. de Vries. I correcetd my silly mistake and managed to plot the function IIC.

Comment: IIC[\[Nu]_, num_, \[CapitalDelta]_] := 
  Log[2, num] - 
   Sum[(q[\[Nu], num, \[CapitalDelta], t]) Log[2, 
      q[\[Nu], num, \[CapitalDelta], t]], {t, 0, num - 1}];                          AbsoluteTiming[Table[IIC[\[Nu], 4, 0.2], {\[Nu], 1, 200, 20}]]                                         ListPlot[Table[{\[Nu], IIC[\[Nu], 100, 0.2]}, {\[Nu], 1, 100}], 
 PlotRange -> All, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]

Comment: @ Sjoerd C. de Vries-in the expression q[\[Nu]_, num_, \[CapitalDelta]_, t_] the summations over d & d by 10 simply to see if their is any way to get it to work, if it goes to infinity,that is very slow to complete, is there any way to converge?